# Converting a JSX object to string

Tags: reactjs, object, jsx, stringify

I have an object in .jsx file that contains JSX.elements here and there. I want to convert it to string, e.g go from this:

```
const data = {
  title: 'Create cat',
  description: 'Creates a new cat',
  react_element: (
    <>
      <span>Create account body here</span>
      <VideoEmbed title="Youtube sample" description="This is a spiderman meme" videoLink="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FKPiqAFt3Rk" />
    </>
  ),
  generatePrettyReactElement: (args: string) => (
    <>
      <span>Create account body here</span>
      <VideoEmbed title="Youtube sample" description="This is a spiderman meme" videoLink="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FKPiqAFt3Rk" />
    </>
  ),
};
```

To this:

```
const string = "const data = { title: 'Create cat', description: 'Creates a new cat', react_element: (<> <span>Create account body here</span> <VideoEmbed title="Youtube sample" description="This is a spiderman meme" videoLink="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FKPiqAFt3Rk" /> </>),generatePrettyReactElement: (args: string) => (<> <span>Create account body here</span><VideoEmbed title="Youtube sample" description="This is a spiderman meme" videoLink="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FKPiqAFt3Rk" /></>),};"
```

I've tried `JSON.stringify(data)` but then it loses JSX.elements, then I've tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-element-to-jsx-string but it only works with JSX.Element and not an object that might contain JSX elements.

Comment: can you share with us what's the reason for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write replacer for JSON.stringify function and use react-element-to-jsx-string for each JSX element.

```
JSON.stringify(data, (value) => {
  if (React.isValidElement(value)) {
     const result = /// do react element stringification of the element
     return result;
  }

  return value;
})
```

Comment: Yep - this is the solution, that's what I ended up doing as well.